# How to delete a named session

Tags: php

I'm using named sessions to store variables for a multi-page form like this:

```
$_SESSION['pages'][0]
$_SESSION['pages'][1]
```

If I want to unset all the variables in $_SESSION['pages'][1] and I use session_unset(); it clears all the variables in both of them.

I know I can unset variables one by one using:

```
unset($_SESSION['pages'][1]['email'])
```

But I'm looking for a way to delete all of `$_SESSION['pages'][1]` while leaving `$_SESSION['pages'][0]` intact

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `unset` on `$_SESSION['pages'][1]`, it's just a normal Array.

```
unset($_SESSION['pages'][1]);
```

Comment: I tried that and i got an error. Maybe the syntax was wrong. I'll try again.

Comment: I had the unset command working correctly, but after that the variables were still unset. But it wasn't the unset command that was the problem, it was something else.